# How do you correctly use the word "shipment" in a sentence?

Tags: word-usage

If I have a shipment with X products, which is one the correct usage:

- At the first shipment we got X products
- On the first shipment we got X products
- In the first shipment we got X products
  or is there something better?

Comment: A shipment is a consignment of goods transported together, so I would use _in_. X product was a part of that shipment.

Answer (score 1):

A “shipment” is a collection of things transported together, and you refer to the members as being “in” that collection.

We treat collections as if they are containers, regardless of whether a physical container exists.

Answer (score 0):

**You got (received) X products *from / in* the first shipment.**

Relevant NGram:

[image]

Although it may look like *from* is by far the best choice, we have to take into account the usages of each word. One normally receives *from* **an entity or a quantity**, while one normally receives *in* **an event or a time period**. The arrival of a shipment is an event and a shipment is a quantity of items.